# golang http client and server can't maintain reliable connection

Tags: http, go

I have a very basic usecase of an http client making a `POST` request to an http server periodically, every 5 seconds.

the client:

```
client := &http.Client{Timeout: 1 * time.Second}

...

for {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    body := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("foo"))
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "http://localhost:8080/foo", body)
    
    ...
    
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    ...

    _ = resp.Body.Close()
}
```

the server:

```
    srv := &http.Server{
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        Addr:         ":9090",
        Handler:      mux,
    }
```

Most of the times the requests are successful. But very randomly they fail with different error message:

```
# the server seems to close the connection
Post http://localhost:8080/foo: read tcp 127.0.0.1:41312->127.0.0.1:9090: read: connection reset by peer
# the client seems to close its own connection unfortunately while performing a request
Post http://localhost:8080/foo: EOF
# this is something that tends to happen, but would result in a retry, which cant work with a POST
Post http://localhost:8080/foo: http: server closed idle connection
```

I can avoid this problem by closing the connection in the request with `req.Close = true`, by disabling keep-alive in the http client, or executing the request every second, instead of every 5 seconds. It seems to be a timing issue.

I can not wrap my head around the fact that I simply cannot maintain a connection between the two without creating a new connection for every request, even though this seems to be the most basic task in the world.

What am I missing?

Comment: @colm.anseo no it pretty much responds instantly

Comment: Client timeout of `1s` is quite short...

Comment: unfortunately changing it to `20s` has not resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you encounter race condition because you have set server `ReadTimeout` to 5s and this is exactly equal to interval between requests. According to the Server documentation:

```
Server struct {
...
    // IdleTimeout is the maximum amount of time to wait for the
    // next request when keep-alives are enabled. If IdleTimeout
    // is zero, the value of ReadTimeout is used. If both are
    // zero, there is no timeout.
    IdleTimeout time.Duration
```

This means that when the client sends further requests, after 5 seconds of sleep, the connection may or may not already be closed. Alternatively, it may be unilaterally closed. Hence the various error messages.

Setting Server `IdleTimeout` value to something higher than 5s should help.